# Installing packages on R fails when loading .Rprofile

Tags: r, install.packages

When I try to install packages in R, installation almost always fails if my `.Rprofile` is loaded. When I load R with the `--vanilla` flag, however, I am able to install packages without problems. Here is the output of an R session with the problem. I think the difficulty is related either to my `.First()` function in the `.Rprofile` or to the history file. [My Rprofile file is here](https://github.com/lmullen/dotfiles/blob/master/r/Rprofile.symlink).

```
$ install.packages("SuppDists")
Installing package into ‘/home/lmullen/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/SuppDists_1.1-9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 140784 bytes (137 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 137 Kb

Loading required package: stats
Loading required package: sp
rgeos version: 0.2-19, (SVN revision 394)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4 
 Polygon checking: TRUE 

rgdal: version: 0.8-10, (SVN revision 478)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.9
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009, [PJ_VERSION: 470]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
Error in .External2(C_loadhistory, file) : no history mechanism available
Calls: .First -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpX42EEZ/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("SuppDists") :
  installation of package ‘SuppDists’ had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you try removing the .First function to see if that helps?

Comment: I'd also only recommend loading any packages an interactive session - and in general, I recommend against loading any packages because it leads to non-reproducible code

Comment: @Dason: I tried removing the .First function, and the error message about the history went away, but the package still did not install.

Comment: @hadley: Thanks for the advice. I completely agree about loading packages. I always run the code through a non-interactive session with the --vanilla flag. But I took your advice and moved all the package loading into the function that checks whether the session is interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Henrik gave me the answer on the R-devel mailing list:

> Using
>
> `if (interactive()) utils::loadhistory(file = "~/.Rhistory")`
>
> should solve your problem.  The reason is that `install.packages()` in
>   turn launches a non-interactive child R process that installs the
>   package.  When that process loads your startup file, it fails, because
>   that function can only be used in interactive mode.

Comment: Here is a link to [Henrik's answer on R-devel mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-installing-packages-when-history-mechanism-is-modified-by-user-profile-td4729360.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the lines in my `.Rprofile` that were causing the problem, though I don't know why they were causing the problem. The `.First` and `.Last` functions were these:

```
.First <- function() {
  utils:::loadhistory(file = "~/.Rhistory")
  cat("\nSuccessfully loaded .Rprofile at", date(), "\n\n")
}

.Last <- function() {
  utils:::savehistory(file = "~/.Rhistory")
}
```

Commenting out the lines about saving and loading history let me install packages.

Comment: still no idea what caused the problem?

Comment: got it, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

### In Ubunto:

I installed it from outside of R and it worked well, thanks to @hugo-raguet :

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
sudo apt-get -y install r-cran-igraph
```

There is no need to install *igraph* later in the R, I believe.